# Pandas aggregating across multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from IPython.display import display

arrays = [['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux'],
         ['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two']]
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(arrays, names=['first', 'second'])
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.arange(8),
                   'B': np.arange(8),
                    'C': np.arange(8)},
                  index=index)
df
```

[image]

I now wanted a dataframe with the contents being the sum of all elements under group 'first' i.e.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>first</th>
    <th>sum</th>     
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>bar</td>
    <td>3</td>    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>baz</td>
    <td>15</td>    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>foo</td>
    <td>27</td>    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>qux</td>
    <td>39</td>    
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried the following code

```
grouped = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(level='first')])
grouped.sum(axis='columns')
```

but this complains with "f() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'". Is there a way to run aggregation functions on multiindex dataframes by suppressing one of the indices?

Comment: @sharatpc Tried that but same error. I am using pandas 0.18.0. Are you using a later version where this works?

Comment: I use 0.21.0. Sorry for deleting the comment but realized columns can be used in place of 1. But I do get the op for level first: bar 1 1 1
baz 5 5 5
foo 9 9 9
qux 13 13 13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Way 1**

This code

```
grouped = df.reset_index().groupby('first').sum()
sum_by_columns = grouped.sum(axis=1).to_frame()
sum_by_columns.columns = ['sum']
print(sum_by_columns)
```

will provide your desired output

```
       sum
first     
bar      3
baz     15
foo     27
qux     39
```

The morale here is that grouped.sum() applies to each column separately.

**Way 2**

You could use your own aggregation function though:

```
sum_by_columns = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(level='first')]).apply(lambda x: x.sum().sum())
sum_by_columns.columns = ['sum']
print(sum_by_columns)
```

It would lead you to the same result. Here, the lambda is applied not to each column, but to each partial dataframe.

**Way 3**

If you need to aggregate across columns, you can first turn them into rows with `df.stack()` method:

```
sum_by_columns = df.stack().groupby(pd.Grouper(level='first')).sum().to_frame()
sum_by_columns.columns = ['sum']
print(sum_by_columns)
```

Comment: This does what I want. Thanks. Would you know how to extend groupby with other aggregation functions in one step? Say if I need the sum and the mean?

Comment: @andrnev, you can use list or even dict of functions and pass them to groupby.aggregate() method, see http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#applying-multiple-functions-at-once

Comment: hmm. Tried print(df.groupby([pd.Grouper(level='first')]).agg([np.sum, np.mean, np.std])) and print(df.groupby([pd.Grouper(level='first')]).aggregate(np.sum, np.mean,np.std)) and both dont seem to produce the aggregate at the index level.

Comment: If you want to aggregate several statistics across all columns, the simplest way is to turn them first into one column: df.stack().groupby(pd.Grouper(level='first')).agg([np.sum, np.mean, np.std])

Answer (score 0):

```
 df.groupby(by="first").sum() will give you, (by="w/e you want them to be group by")
            A   B   C
    first            
    bar     1   1   1
    baz     5   5   5
    foo     9   9   9
    qux    13  13  13

 df.groupby(by="first").sum().sum(axis=1) will give you 
first
bar     3
baz    15
foo    27
qux    39
```